# End of Video File OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Does anyone know how to check for the EOF(End of File) condition in OpenCV/C++ ? For example to check for empty file condition we can use the isEmpty() method, which returns a Boolean value. Is there any such method for catching EOF exceptions ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

There is also a similar function called `empty()` for you to use. Check out:

```
VideoCapture cap("your_video.avi");
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

Mat frame;
while(1) // looply reading frames from the video file
{
    cap >> frame; // try to get an image frame

    if (frame.empty())
    {
        // reach to the end of the video file
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great method. I will check it out, thanks !!

Comment: Doesn't work man. cannot convert "cap >> frame" to a boolean value.